# Initializing an internally allocated matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have to write a constructor for implementing a function for initializing an internally allocated matrix. The given code looks like (only constructor):

```
Matrix(const float* m, size_t n) : _n(n), _m(0lu)
    {
        //Missing
    }
```

So, my first question is: What does the part behind the ':' mean (`_n(n), _m(0lu)`)?
Furthermore, as far as I know, I need a return pointer to the memory I am allocating. Is this correct? My first idea was to use `posix_memalign(...)`. Would this be correct?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this basic object:

```
class Matrix
{
   // stuff
private:
    size_t _n;
    float* _m;
}
```

The part of the constructor is an initialization list. It is synonymous to wiring:

```
Matrix(const float* m, size_t n)
{
    _n = n;
    _m = 0lu;
}
```

Here is a good decription, why you want to use them: [[10.6] Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html)

But that does not solve your initial problem: **"function for initializing an internally allocated matrix"**

What the constructor does is copy the size (n) and initialize the pointer to NULL. (NULL is synonymous with 0 [1]) So you need some way to **internally allocate** and initialize.

I have one problem with the Matrix class. Normally a matrix has 2 dimension, so either it is a NxN matrix or n is the element count and we have no idea what dimension the matrix is. I will assume that it is NxN matrix, since this is quite often used in computer graphics.

Step 1: **internally allocated**

So, allocate some memory:

```
_m = new float[n*n];
```

This can replace the assignment to NULL, since why should it be first set to NULL and then change right after.

Step2: **initialized**

Assuming that the calling code put sufficient data into `m`, just use `memcpy`:

```
 std::memcpy(_m, m, n*n*sizeof(float));
```

If you feel masochistic, you can also copy the elements each:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
{
     _m[i] = m[i];
}
```

So your final constructor looks like so:

```
#include <cstring>

Matrix(const float* m, size_t n)
: _n(n), _m(new float[n*n])
{
    std::memcpy(_m, m, n*n*sizeof(float));
}
```

Finally, since you allocated memory you should not forget to delete it in the destructor:

```
Matrix::~Matrix() 
{
    delete [] _m;
}
```

*Note the array deleting operator.*

[1] In C++11 and C99 this is not fully true under certain circumstances, but these are details and irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, I got a bit confused with "allocate" (I thought about "alignment" and stuff like that)...

Answer (score 2):

```
:_n(n), _m(0lu)
```

is member internalizer list. Means `_n`(which seems to be member variable) is assing `n` to it and simialr for `_m`

More details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)